# Remove the character "$" from product view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, opencart

I am using OpenCart 1.5.1.3.1 and have a quick question. When viewing a product, on the product's page, I wish to remove the character "$" next to the amount, eg "$20.00" to "20.00".

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: did u try using replace()

Comment: I believe there is an option to disable currency in OpenCart. Search for that option :)

Comment: What about going to your administration *Settings* -> *Localization* -> *Currencies* -> select *US Dollar* -> *Edit* -> remove the *sign before* -> *Save* -> done?

Comment: Thanks shadyyx. Your idea gave the solution. And thanks to everybody else. I didn't got time to implement their view.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function.

So your value will be trimmed like this: `trim($value, "$");`

Answer (score -1):

How to fix the string that's sent to the view in the first place:

Locate the following line in `/catalog/controllers/product/product.php` (line 315 in v1.5.6.4):

```
$this->data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
```

Replace it with:

```
$this->data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate(6, $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), '', '', false);
```

You can add the same arguments `, '', '', false` to the end of other calls to `$this->currency` to remove the prefix/suffix from other items (e.g. tax)

Comment: I would like to see you editing this in whole OpenCart... Why even modifying the code when it could be *turned off* easily in administration? And what if he needed to turn it off only for Dollar but not for GB Pound? Would you then introduce `if-else` in the code?

Comment: @shadyyx He specified the product page. Turning it off in administration turns it off EVERYWHERE. If that's what he wanted, then he worded it poorly, not my fault. I do think it's safe to assume that wanting to remove the $ means he wants to remove the currency prefix/suffix, whether that's USD or otherwise.